# Http Response Builder Deprecated in 3.6 Mule? But able to see inside HTTP Listener Component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have a small query to be clarified Regarding HTTP Response builder. I can able to see response builder inside HTTP listener in 3.6 ,3.7 and also 3.8. But the url says https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-response-builder Response builder is deprecated in 3.6 or later.

```
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="${inbound.path}" allowedMethods="POST,GET" doc:name="HTTP">
         <http:response-builder>
            <http:header headerName="check-ID" value="#[sessionVars.transactionId]"/>
        </http:response-builder> 
    </http:listener>
```

Also I have seen separate `response builder component` in old version

```
 <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/html" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>.
```

Which one is actually deprecated. Confused. I'm doing changes in response builder in 3.6 and added the changes for `Response Builder inside HTTP listener`. But need to make sure i'm not using the deprecated one anyway.

What is the actual difference between the above two.( Configuring `inside HTTP listener` and as separate `Response builder component`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is deprecated as it is part of the HTTP Transport which is deprecated. The first one is part of the new HTTP Module which replaces the transport.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Trying to migrate to 3.9.0. Am I right that you get a warning even though you choose the first one?

Comment: Yes that is correct @Derp . It warns you regardless. Nothing to worry about.